# YUM ERROR: Failed to retrieve group file for repository: rhel-x86_64-server-7

Tags: yum, redhat-satellite

A week ago, a `yum update` on all my Rehdat 7 servers, outputs the following error:

**Error:**

```
Failed to retrieve group file for repository: rhel-x86_64-server-7
```

I tried doing a `yum clean all`, but that did not work.

I suspect it's a problem with the the satellite redhat software server that we use here.  I registered a totally new node with that server, but the same error occurs.

A yum check-update after clean all with debugging on shows it tries to download the file but fails.  But downloads all the other files.

Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos,
              : subscription-manager
Adding en_US.UTF-8 to language list
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Config time: 0.072
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Building updates object
Setting up Package Sacks
rhel-x86_64-server-7                                     | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                               | 770 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7/primary                             |  33 MB     00:03
rhel-x86_64-server-7                                                23361/23361
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1                             | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1/group                       |  104 B     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1/updateinfo                  | 915 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1/primary                     | 3.1 MB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-rhscl-1                                        10948/10948
rhel-x86_64-server-7-thirdparty-oracle-java              | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-thirdparty-oracle-java/group        |  104 B     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-thirdparty-oracle-java/updateinfo   |  15 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-7-thirdparty-oracle-java/primary      |  129 B     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7                              | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7/group                        |  104 B     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7/updateinfo                   | 241 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7/primary                      | 317 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-extras-7                                           1076/1076
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7                            | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7/group                      |  31 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7/updateinfo                 | 2.0 MB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7/primary                    | 4.3 MB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-optional-7                                       17521/17521
rhel-x86_64-server-rh-common-7                           | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-rh-common-7/group                     |  104 B     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-rh-common-7/updateinfo                |  29 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-rh-common-7/primary                   |  55 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-rh-common-7                                          235/235
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7                       | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7/group                 |  40 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7/updateinfo            |  56 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7/primary               | 112 kB     00:00
rhel-x86_64-server-supplementary-7                                      310/310
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7                           | 1.5 kB     00:00
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7/group                     |  104 B     00:00
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7/updateinfo                |  15 kB     00:00
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7/primary                   |  24 kB     00:00
rhn-tools-rhel-x86_64-server-7

Comment: Do you know what version of Satellite software you're using?

Comment: Can you add your repo files from /etc/yum.repo.d/ ??

Comment: also include output of /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/rhnplugin.conf

Comment: @VivekKanadiya There is nothing in yum.report.d other than the redhat generated file, which just contains comments, because it's receiving the repos from the satellite server.

Comment: @Deeh rhnplugin.conf just contains:[main]
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 1
timeout = 120

Comment: I've modified my original post to show output from yum check-update